# Would invisible blaster bolts make a more effective weapon against the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, weapon

It struck me that having blaster bolts be invisible would prevent the Jedi being able to tell – purely using their vision – where to move, and instead force them to rely exclusively on their prescience.

**Why aren't the Jedi's enemies equipped with those sorts of weapons?**

Comment: Blaster fire seems to not leave any distinct visible marks from a distance, so how do you tell that you hit if you're firing invisible lasers?

Comment: @Theik the thing you hit should fall down...

Comment: Yeah, what's preventing the guy from falling over and feigning death and then shooting you in the back if neither you nor the enemy has any visual way of identifying a hit from a miss?

Comment: The same thing as with bullets?  If you aren't sure if you hit the target, keep shooting.  If they're laying down feigning death, it should be pretty easy to hit them (unless you're a stormtrooper).

Comment: Hi. I note you haven't accepted any answers for this question yet. If my answer addresses the question, would you please consider answering it for future viewers? If not, please let me know where I can improve it!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question up into the title.

Comment: @Richard: Your edits makes Soong's answer sound like he's answering a completely different question when it made some sense before. But I agree, you seem to have focused on the asker's intent.

Comment: @ellesdil - The problem is that he didn't answer the question asked, he answered the question in the title.

Answer (score 8):

A Jedi doesn't need to see the bolt of energy to be able to deflect it. They would know where it would be via the force.

This can be shown by Luke in *A New Hope* when he deflects the training droid bolts with the blast visor down.

[image]

Watching the films and the rate of fire the Jedi often deal with it would be very unlikely that they use vision at all to deflect the bolts and solely use prescience any way.

Therefore there wouldn't be much use for them to be invisible from a killing Jedi point of view.

Invisible bolts may be useful in an assassin or spy type of role.

I half remember an EU book where there was a rifle that fired invisible bolts that was used to frame Han. I think this was one of the Centrepoint trilogy books. There were Noghri in it.

Answer (score 4):

It's to do with the mechanics of how a blaster works.  Per the [Blaster page on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blaster#Blaster_mechanics):

> When the blaster was fired, a small amount of gas moved from the
>   cartridge through the Heter valve into the gas conversion enabler
>   chamber, commonly called the "XCiter". In this chamber, the power pack
>   energized the gas, before it passed into the actuating blaster module,
>   where the now extremely high-energy gas was transformed into a
>   compressed beam of intense energy particles, **coupled with intense
>   light**. The particle beam was then focused through a prismatic crystal
>   or a similar device, which generated a deadly high-energy particle
>   beam, fired from the emitter nozzle as **a bolt of glowing energy**. **The
>   color of the bolt depended on the gas used and the type of focusing
>   device, and could vary from red to blue to orange to white**.

So, if a gas could be used which was transparent, then it probably would work, but my guess is that there isn't such a gas that would be effective for use in a blaster which is why they are forced (pun intended) to use a gas which results in a coloured bolt.

Comment: Also, "coupled with **intense light**". Light isn't transparent. Not really. Muzzle flash alone would be enough for a skilled eye. Plus, they can see where the blaster is pointed at

Comment: I always interpreted the deflection of a blaster with a lightsaber as something the jedi is only be able to do with precognition. He looks into the future and sees where exactly he is hit and puts his saber in position to prevent it. If it depends on reflex and reaction and visual perception, use todays guns to kill a jedi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, invisible blaster bolts would be effective, to some Jedi. Not that many. Now, that video of Luke deflecting the bolts is a good representation of a Jedi stretching out into the Force to see. However, Luke releases himself into the Force because he's expecting the attack. An assassin with a sniper rifle could catch a Jedi unawares, and if the bolt is invisible, the Jedi might not think to stretch into the Force. This probably applies to only a couple Jedi, because most others would almost always sense something through the Force. An assassin wouldn't get it because either it's not available or it costs too much.

Comment: Adding any sources or links that could help support your answer would attract more attention.